# Oracle apex inline dialog width

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I have an oracle apex(5.0) inline dialog region. I set it's size large (720*480) in template option. but now I want to increase the width of this region. how can I do this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7d3l.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just after posting the question I found the answer. It worked for me I changed the size to 1200*580. at the 'CSS Classes' option add

```css
js-dialog-size1200x580
```